# How to prove $(\neg \phi \rightarrow \phi) \rightarrow \phi$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

How to prove $(\neg \phi \rightarrow \phi) \rightarrow \phi$? I know, that if I check the truth table I am able to verify it. But how can I prove it from axioms? In school we use these axioms

(1) $\phi \rightarrow \phi \lor \psi$ 
(2) $\phi \lor \psi \rightarrow \psi \lor \phi$ 
(3) $\phi \lor (\psi \rightarrow \chi) \rightarrow (\phi \lor \psi \rightarrow \phi \lor \chi) $ 
(4) $\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi \land \psi)$ 
(5) $\neg \phi \lor \neg \psi \rightarrow \neg (\phi \land \psi)$ 
(6) $\top$ 
(7) $\neg \bot$ 
plus Modus Ponens. I made many attempts but I never get the result I want.

Comment: Can you use modus nolens?  If $\phi$ were false then $\lnot \phi$ would be true and therefore $(\lnot \phi \to \phi)\to (T \to \phi)\to \phi \to (\phi \land \lnot \phi)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: "Modus nolens"?  Maybe you mean modus tollens?

Comment: Are those the only rules you have?  They seem strange to me because, for example, I see no way to prove simple tautologies like $\phi\to(\phi\land\phi)$.  Item (4) proves $\phi\to(\phi\to(\phi\land\phi))$ but without some sort of hypothesis-conclusion rule you have no way to get rid of the extra $\phi\to$.

Comment: Yes, I mean modus tollens.  I swear it was called modus nolens back in the 80s.....  (Of course, it couldn't have been, but I swear it was.)

Comment: Your axioms are all implications whose conclusions are either a conjunction, a disjunction, or a negation - never a formula on its own. So unless I'm mistaken, your task is impossible. Are you allowed to use a rule like $\phi \wedge \phi \rightarrow \phi$ or $\phi \vee \phi \rightarrow \phi$?

Comment: Yeah there seems to be a lack of concluding $(\phi \land \psi) \to \phi$ and others.

Comment: Without any further axioms involving $\bot$ and $\top$, 6 and 7 are pretty useless. I am thinking there must be more axioms in your system than the ones you list here.

Comment: I am trying to prove Deduction Lemma from Van den Dries notes, where part of the proof is "Using the $L-tautology$ $(\neg \forall x \phi \rightarrow \forall x \phi) \rightarrow \forall x \phi$ and Modus Ponens we get etc." And I don't understand the $L-tautology$. We also have Generalisation and Existentional rule, axioms of equality and Quantifier axioms, but I don't see that they would help

Comment: If these are the notes (https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main2.pdf), check p.39. The axioms listed there don't match what you've put in your question.

Comment: @Bram28 The $\top$ and $\bot$ rules can actually be used.  For example, (4) gives us $\top \to (\psi\to\top\land\psi)$ and then from (6) we can get $\psi\to\top\land\psi$, which is something, at least by the standards of these very incomplete axioms.

Comment: @MJD You're right! Thanks!

Comment: @JasonSwanson I know that axioms there are different from those we use in lecture. I wanted to do the proof using axioms we were given from our professor. Those notes you posted are source we can use to study so I wanted to use them as a guideline for the proof. Actually it is supposed to be a proof of an easy observation (not the deduction lemma itself) $\Gamma \vdash \phi \implies \Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$, but since there are different axioms in Van den Dries notes I cannot do the proof there properly.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this proof using the axioms you provided. All the axioms you provided are constructively valid (meaning they can be proved in intuitionistic propositional logic), but $(\neg \phi \to \phi) \to \phi$ is not constructively valid.

You need some sort of principle like proof by contradiction, proof by contrapositive, or the law of excluded middle to be able to prove such things.

Comment: I am trying to prove Deduction Lemma from Van den Dries notes, where part of the proof is "Using the $L-tautology$ $(\neg \forall x \phi \rightarrow \forall x \phi) \rightarrow \forall x \phi$ and Modus Ponens we get etc." And I don't understand the $L-tautology$. We also have Generalisation and existentional rule and quantifier axioms, but I don't see that they would help.

Answer (score -2):

I got:
$(\neg \phi \rightarrow \phi) \rightarrow \phi \equiv_{(\rightarrow)} (\neg(\neg \phi) \vee \phi) \rightarrow \phi \equiv_{\neg(\neg)} (\phi \vee \phi) \rightarrow \phi \equiv \phi \rightarrow \phi \equiv_{(\rightarrow)} \neg\phi \vee \phi \equiv_{(basic \; tautology)} \; T$